# .extend equivalent in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, syntax, coffeescript

Is there another way to express this code in Coffeescript, i dont really like the current result.

Javascript:

```
videojs.ChromecastTech = videojs.MediaTechController.extend({
    init: function() {
        console.log("TEST");
    }
});
```

Coffeescript:

```
videojs.ChromecastTech = videojs.MediaTechController.extend
  init: ->
    console.log "TEST"
```

Comment: I don't know enough about coffeescript and that is why I am not posting this as answer, but I think you have a syntax error: all functions available from JS are available from coffeescript, including .extend, so the problem maybe is something about the syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end the solution was

```
class vjs.ChromecastTech extends vjs.MediaTechController
    constructor: -> console.log "TEST"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
videojs.ChromecastTech = videojs.MediaTechController.extend init: ->
  console.log "TEST"
  return
```